# Loading different shapefile in SharpMap?

Tags: shapefile, c#, sharpmap

I am currently working on sharpmap project with the need to work on offline maps. As i am fresher in this field,I am following the sharpmap tutorial and facing a problem with loading new shape files in the given tutorial code.

For Example :

```
SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer("States");
        vlay.DataSource = new SharpMap.Data.Providers.ShapeFile("path_to_data\\states_ugl.shp", true);
```

At this line of code,if i pass a different shapefile,code builds with a blank background or no display. 
I have tried with different shape files with different sizes but the result is the same. It only works for the mentioned states_ugl.shp file given in the code.

Comment: Cross-posted as http://stackoverflow.com/q/38262703/820534

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is look at the sample code the is in the SharpMap solution.
Source code: 
   older on CodePlex https://sharpmap.codeplex.com/

Current Fork on GitHub https://github.com/SharpMap/SharpMap
It was pretty easy to get to compile using VS2013 or VS2015.
Open SharpMap.sln
Take a look at Examples\WinFormSamples and Examples\DemoWinForm projects

A couple things I learned over the years using shapeFiles.
 - Older shapefiles mid 1990s can be problematic to use.
   (I have a volcanoes shape file what had a duplicate column name (allowable in DBF but not MS access or FoxPro). And older versions SharpMap would error out

- Check shapefile projection/Coordindations. Most common issue is the shape file is plotted to an incorrect position due coordinate transformation error.
- Use a viewer like ESRI ArcGIS Explorer to validate the shapefile.

Comment: Thans Sir i finally cleared my doubt and code is running.

Comment: Sir can u tell me how to draw a circle on a given layer or on a shapefile?Is there any way to draw a circle knowing the center point and the radius?Being a beginner i have very less knowledge of this part.Also if u can tell me if it is necessary to add a layer on existing layer while drawing a circle or we can draw it on the same existing layer of the shapefile?Thanks

Comment: sory forgot to mention using sharpmap only.Thanks.Please can anyone guide me through this?Thanks again.